# SQLite3, Select From Two Tables One with Priority?

Tags: sqlite, select, join, union

So I have two sqlite3 tables

Table 1

```
ID Color Value
1 red    5
2 green  3
3 yellow 5
4 blue   1
5 white  4
```

Table 2

```
ID Color Value
2 green  6
3 yellow 2
5 white  3
```

What I would like to do with one select if possible is:

```
ID Color Value
1 red    5
2 green  6
3 yellow 2
4 blue   1
5 white  3
```

So use the record from table 1 unless it exists in table 2.  if the record exists in table 2 use that instead.

I looked at unions but no luck.  I added a forth column with a 1 or 0 in it, 1 being table 2 data and tried to prioritize for table two with an order by/limit 1 but that didn't work either.

I'm hoping for one select that will just do it automatically without me have to provide the select with a where clause and items to exclude so that I would have to concantenate a string query.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

```
select t1.ID, case when t2.Color is not null 
                   then t2.Color
                   else t1.Color
              end as Color,
              case when t2.Value is not null 
                   then t2.Value
                   else t1.Value
              end as Value
from table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

### edit

An even shorter version (thanks to Doug) is:

```
select t1.ID, 
       coalesce(t2.Color, t1.Color) as Color, 
       coalesce(t2.Value, t1.Value) as Value
from table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: Your solution looks fine, but you can replace the case statements with `coalesce(t2.Color, t1.Color) as Color, coalesce(t2.Value, t1.Value) as Value`